# How to implement Validation Controls with multiple submit buttons

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

[image]

There are two submit buttons on web form, Required field validation is there, i want if i click first submit button, it doesn't check the second submit.
Mean i only want that only first text box Required validation must work?
what should i have to do that i can segregate validation on multiple submit buttons
For more detail, snap shot is included.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you need is [validationGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property

The required Filed Validator will have following property

```
 <asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="RequiredFieldValidator2"
      ...
      validationgroup="Group1"
      ...
      runat="Server">
    </asp:requiredfieldvalidator>
```

And associated button

```
 <asp:button id="Button1" 
      text="Validate" 
      causesvalidation="true"
      validationgroup="Group1"
      runat="Server" />
```

In this way you can organise which validation to perform on any specific button click